# tengo problemas para ordenar de mayor a menor mi join con query builder

Tags: laravel-5, sql, join

tengo problemas para ordenar la query de mayor a menor por la fecha "created_at"
no arroja error  y si me muestra los datos de la query pero solo no los ordena
estés es el código

```
$listado = DB::table('lotes')->join('producciondiarias', function ($join)use($user_id){
                                $join->on('lotes.id','=','producciondiarias.lote_id')
                                ->where('lotes.user_id','=',$user_id)                                      
                                ->orderBy('producciondiarias.created_at','desc');
                                })->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo solucione, mi problema es que estaba mal donde agrupaba, la forma correcta es esta

```
$listado = DB::table('lotes')->join('producciondiarias', function ($join)use($user_id){
                                $join->on('lotes.id','=','producciondiarias.lote_id')
                                ->where('lotes.user_id','=',$user_id);
                                })->orderBy('producciondiarias.created_at','desc')->get();
```